# Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 124 of page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I keep getting this error in a fresh drupal install with fusion and a custom fusion subtheme:

```
Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 124 of /home/username/public_html/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
```

Would anyone happen to have any clue as to what is causing this?

Comment: This is not specific to Drupal and may be better suited for another StackExchange site.  In short though, you're trying to access a variable that is not yet set.  You can find a few solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index

Comment: Apparently, I had a hard break in my theme's .info file and that was causing all sorts of problems.  When I removed it, everything resolved itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct highlighted is a region name and you might have not defined it in you theme info file which is why it is throwing this error.

Give me more details of your info file and your page tpl file so that I can guide you in a better way.

Comment: Thanks junedkazi - Apparently, I had a hard break in my theme's .info file and that was causing all sorts of problems. When I removed it, everything resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone face the same issue :

Search for any "*.info" file in your drupal repo that has no line similar to "name = xxxx".

The "*.info" file might be outside of your themes.

For instance, my problem was due to a file named "lcov.info" in a grunt module (grunt-svgmin) in my theme. I happended "name = lcov is not a theme" at the beginning of the file and the issue fade away. I'll check svg-min later.

for more, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105233/26878